# filter result by taking out a matching regex in pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have some data that contains a url string, which all have some variety substring embeded.

my goal to to get a set of results which have the substring removed from the string:

e.g.

rawdata: {
  id Long,
  url String
}

here's some sample rawdata:
1,/213112341_v1.html
2,43524254243_v2.html
5,/000000_v3.html
5,/000000_v4.html

the result I want is:

1,/213112341.html
2,43524254243.html
5,/000000.html

so basically remove teh subversion number( _v1|_v2|v3|_v4) from the url and create unique results.

How do I do that in pig?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to do something like the following:

```
FOREACH data GENERATE id, CONCAT(REGEX_EXTRACT(url, '(/?[0-9]*)_,',1),'.html');
```

EDIT:

How about trying the following if the data is more complicated

```
FOREACH data GENERATE id, CONCAT(STRSPLIT(url, '_v[0-9]',1),'.html')
```

That should get everything before the version #, with the concat adding the .html back in. If both the before verson number and after verison number sections are more comlicated you could do something like:

```
FOREACH data GENERATE id, CONCAT(FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(url, '_v[0-9]',2)))
```

Comment: but what i really want is to get rid of the regex matching part, not to extract the rest, that content is more complicated than the example and harder to accurately define.

Comment: updated the post with a few more ideas. Hopefully they are more useful to you. they don't require precise regex definitions, so that should make it easier.